# How to repeatedly ask for file name as command-line argument, until the passed input is correct?

Tags: command-line, arguments

I know how to get input from command-line. But if the input (file name) they pass in throws file not found exception, how would I have them try again until the file name entered is correct? (Java)

Comment: What environment are you working in?  What shell language?  What code have you tried?

Comment: I'm working on eclipse and the language is java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the command-line arguments are invalid, just exit the program with the expectation (possibly made explicit via an error message) that the user will then run the program again with the correct arguments.  I don't have any facts to back this up, but having the program remain running and harassing the user to input a new set of command-line arguments does not seem like good design.

Comment: Sure, if there is only one prompt. But what if there are 10 prompts, and only the last response is invalid. You think it is a good design to force the user to start again from the beginning? Or perhaps the script runs 1 hour before issuing the prompt. There are many scenarios where the OP's request is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: @dbenham: Based on the OP's use of the phrase "command line" rather than "standard input," I'm assuming the arguments are all actual *command-line arguments*, i.e., passed in through `argv` rather than a series of prompts to `stdout` & reads from `stdin`.  If they are actually `argv` arguments, then starting over *is* good design.

Comment: Ah, you are correct. I had Windows batch script on my mind as this question comes up as part of my SO filter looking for batch related questions. The system will not let me undo my down vote unless the question is edited :( The OP should probably alter the script/program to verify existence of file before doing any work. (basic transaction control)

Comment: Thanks and I apoligize for the confusion.